# using rand MethodError: no method matching isless(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Float64)

Tags: if-statement, julia

If I run the following code,

```
A = 0.2 
if rand(1)<0.85
   println(A)
end
```

the error is

```
MethodError: no method matching isless(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:

isless(!Matched::Missing, ::Any) at missing.jl:87

isless(!Matched::Float64, ::Float64) at float.jl:465

isless(!Matched::AbstractFloat, ::AbstractFloat) at operators.jl:165
```

I know that this is a simple code. But no idea why Julia is throwing this error. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `if rand()<0.85`. `rand(1)` generates a 1 element `Vector` of `Float64`. `rand()` generates a `Float64`.